# Pass hidden field to asp-controller action that shows up modal dialog (asp.net core)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

In my code I'm trying to call an asp-controller action with some arguments. This controller action shows a partial view as modal dialog. View code:

```
  <div style="float: right">
            <a asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="MyAction" asp-route-projectId="@Model.ProjectId" asp-route-tag="@Model.Tag" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal">Execute</a>
        </div>
```

My controller action signature:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction(int projectId, string tag)
```

Now I also want to include a hidden field, and pass it as an argument to my controller.

```
 <div style="float: right">
            <a asp-controller="MyController" asp-action="MyAction" asp-route-projectId="@Model.ProjectId" asp-route-tag="@Model.Tag" asp-for-MyNewArgument="MyHiddenField" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal">Execute</a>
        </div>
```

What is the syntax to do that? I have tried to solve this by including a hidden field on top and doing a form submit, (passing a view model to my controller signature) but unfortunately this makes my modal dialog show as a complete page, instead of a modal dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're relying on the "remote" functionality of Bootstrap's modal, which is actually deprecated. Essentially, what's happening currently is that Bootstrap is recognizing the the modal activating link has an href to another page, so it's actually performing an AJAX request for that URL and loading it into the modal's body for you. Because this is happening automatically, you have no control over (to pass in a hidden field value or anything else), and as stated previously, you're relying on deprecated functionality that can be removed in any subsequent release of Bootstrap. Additionally, Bootstrap will only load the remote content once, the first time the modal is shown. So, if the hidden input changes after the fact, no new content will be retrieved based on that.

Long and short, you should handle this yourself, with your own JavaScript.

```
$('#modal-container').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var $modal = $(this);
    $.get(e.relatedTarget.href, {
        MyHiddenFieldName: $('#MyHiddenField').val()
    }, function (html) {
        $modal.find('.modal-content').html(html);
    });
});
```